# Connection between [[stage_in]], MTLVertexDescriptor and MTKMesh

Tags: swift, graphics, 3d, metal, metalkit

What is the connection between:

1. Using `[[stage_in]]` in a Metal Shader
2. Using `MTLVertexDescriptor`
3. Using `MTKMesh`

For example

1. Is it possible to use `[[stage_in]]` without using `MTLVertexDescriptor`?
2. Is it possible to use `MTLVertexDescriptor` without using `MTKMesh`, but an array of a custom struct based data structure? Such as `struct Vertex {...}, Array<Vertex>`?
3. Is it possible to use `MTKMesh` without using `MTLVertexDescriptor`? For example using the same struct based data structure?

I didn't find this information on the internet, and the Metal Shading Language Specification doesn't even include the words "descriptor" or "mesh".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. No. If you try to create a render pipeline state from a pipeline descriptor without a vertex descriptor, and the corresponding vertex function has a `[[stage_in]]` parameter, the pipeline state creation call will fail.
2. Yes. After all, when you draw an `MTKMesh`, you're still obligated to call `setVertexBuffer(...)` with the buffers wrapped by the mesh's constituent `MTKMeshBuffer`s. You could just as readily create an `MTLBuffer` yourself and copy your custom vertex structs into it.
3. Yes. Instead of having a `[[stage_in]]` parameter, you'd have a parameter attributed with `[[buffer(0)]]` (assuming all of the vertex data is interleaved in a single vertex buffer) of type `MyVertexType *`, as well as a `[[vertex_id]]` parameter that tells you where to index into that buffer.

Here's an example of setting the vertex buffers from an `MTKMesh` on a render command encoder:

```
for (index, vertexBuffer) in mesh.vertexBuffers.enumerated() {
    commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer.buffer, offset: vertexBuffer.offset, index: index)
}
```

`vertexBuffer` is of type `MTKMeshBuffer`, while its `buffer` property is of type `MTLBuffer`; I mention this because it can be confusing.

Here is one way in which you might create a vertex descriptor to tell Model I/O and MetalKit to lay out the mesh data you're loading:

```
let mdlVertexDescriptor = MDLVertexDescriptor()
mdlVertexDescriptor.attributes[0] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributePosition, format: MDLVertexFormat.float3, offset: 0, bufferIndex: 0)
mdlVertexDescriptor.attributes[1] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeNormal, format: MDLVertexFormat.float3, offset: 12, bufferIndex: 0)
mdlVertexDescriptor.attributes[2] = MDLVertexAttribute(name: MDLVertexAttributeTextureCoordinate, format: MDLVertexFormat.float2, offset: 24, bufferIndex: 0)
mdlVertexDescriptor.layouts[0] = MDLVertexBufferLayout(stride: 32)
```

You can create a corresponding `MTLVertexDescriptor` in order to create a render pipeline state suitable for rendering such a mesh:

```
let vertexDescriptor = MTKMetalVertexDescriptorFromModelIO(mdlVertexDescriptor)!
```

Here's a vertex struct that matches that layout:

```
struct VertexIn {
    float3 position  [[attribute(0)]];
    float3 normal    [[attribute(1)]];
    float2 texCoords [[attribute(2)]];
};
```

Here's a stub vertex function that consumes one of these vertices:

```
vertex VertexOut vertex_main(VertexIn in [[stage_in]])
{
}
```

And finally, here's a vertex struct and vertex function you could use to render the exact same mesh data *without* a vertex descriptor:

```
struct VertexIn {
    packed_float3 position;
    packed_float3 normal;
    packed_float2 texCoords;
};

vertex VertexOut vertex_main(device VertexIn *vertices [[buffer(0)]],
                             uint vid [[vertex_id]])
{
    VertexIn in = vertices[vid];
}
```

Note that in this last case, I need to mark the struct members as *packed* since by default, Metal's simd types are padded for alignment purposes (specifically, the stride of a `float3` is **16** bytes, not 12 as we requested in our vertex descriptor).

Comment: Hi @warrenm, The last case, does it work in the lasted shader version iOS 12? For a very similar implementation, my old codebase is getting error "vertex function has invalid return type 'ColorInOut'". Any idea, plz help.